# Android: Convert image object to bitmap does not work

Tags: android, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am trying to convert image object to bitmap, but it return null.

```
image = reader.acquireLatestImage();

                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length,null);
```

The image itself is jpeg image, I can save it to the disk fine, the reason I want to convert to bitmap is because I want to do final rotation before saving it to the disk.
Digging in the Class BitmapFactory I see this line.

```
bm = nativeDecodeByteArray(data, offset, length, opts);
```

This line return null.
Further Digging with the debugger

```
private static native Bitmap nativeDecodeByteArray(byte[] data, int offset,
            int length, Options opts);
```

This suppose to return Bitmap object but it return null.

Any tricks.. or ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't copied bytes.You checked capacity but not copied bytes.

```
ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
buffer.get(bytes);
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length,null);
```

Comment: This does not work for me with a nv21 Image. Is this limited to one of the possible Image formats?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to decode an empty array, you just create it but never copy the image data to it.

You can try:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
byte[] bytes = buffer.array();
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length,null);
```

As you say it doesn't work, then we need to copy the buffer manually ... try this :)

```
    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
    buffer.get(bytes);
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length,null);
```

Comment: ByteBuffer.Java

@throws UnsupportedOperationException If this buffer is not backed by an accessible array