# How to display an `Image` in the `ImageView`?

Tags: android, image, imageview, android-camera2

I have an `ImageView` object acquired from the .xml file:

```
mCameraView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
```

I record an image taken from the camera many times a second. For each new image frame the following method gets called.

```
@Override
public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
    Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
    mCameraView.somehowDisplay(image); // HOW?
}
```

I want place the image into the image view: How to do that?

Comment: more details please....where is the 'image' located? In the apps context? In the gallery?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26673127/115145

Comment: @DroiDev, the image is taken from the camera. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
buffer.get(bytes);
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length,null);
mCameraView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

This should work.

[Reference Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44486188/android-convert-image-object-to-bitmap-does-not-work)

Comment: Hmm, this does successfully convert the Image object into the Bitmap object, but the image is not shown on the screen.

Comment: I think you are going to need to override a method onActivityResult. Look into it.